# Problema con tickers en go

Tags: go

Buenos días, espero me puedan apoyar. Estoy haciendo un dummy para probar los tickers en go:

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func main(){
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500) 
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C { 
            fmt.Println("Tic a las", t)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1500) 
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Ticker detenido:", time.Now())

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

En teoria el ticker se ejecuta cada 500 milisegundos y yo lo detengo al pasar 1500 milisegundos, por lo que deberia aparecer 3 impresiones del ticker (en teoria). Sin embargo obtuve la siguiente salida:

```
Tic a las 2016-04-13 09:56:11.8632579 -0500 CDT
Tic a las 2016-04-13 09:56:12.363399 -0500 CDT
Ticker detenido: 2016-04-13 09:56:12.8634635 -0500 CDT
```

Así que, agregue las 3 ultimas lineas del código para terminar el programa cuando se presione una tecla, y el probar de nuevo me encontré con esto:

```
Tic a las 2016-04-13 10:08:15.4709006 -0500 CDT
Tic a las 2016-04-13 10:08:15.9713121 -0500 CDT
Ticker detenido: 2016-04-13 10:08:16.4714132 -0500 CDT
Tic a las 2016-04-13 10:08:16.4714132 -0500 CDT
```

Como pueden observar las dos ultimas lineas imprimen 2016-04-13 10:08:16.**4714132**, es la misma fecha hora incluso en milisegundos, pero se ejecuta primero la impresión de main y yo necesito que se imprima primero la impresión del ticker. ¿Hay alguna forma de corregir esto? ¿Alguna forma de darle prioridad al hilo del ticker sobre el de main?
Espero me puedan apoyar
Gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿Pasa lo mismo en todas las ejecuciones? ¿Es consistente el resultado que te da?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo en todas las ejecuciones, lo he corrido como 20 veces para ver si solo era alguna especie de probabilidad, pero me ha pasado así, y ya me canse de probar. Por eso publique la pregunta.

Comment: Que crees, probe la vez 21 y salio bien. ¿Sabes como arreglarlo?

Comment: El ticker imprimio 11:06:17.0100094 y el main 11:06:17.0109602 por eso salio bien. Obvio no son iguales, el problema es cuando son iguales hasta en milisegundos. Pero de como 20 veces que he probado solo 1 han salido diferentes los milisegundos y fue la unica vez que salio bien.

Comment: Interesante, voy a tratar de replicar tu problema para ver si puedo arreglarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regresando a tu primer intento veo que todo está "bien".

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500) 
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C { 
            fmt.Println("Tic a las", t)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1500) 
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Ticker detenido:", time.Now())
}
```

Al ejecutarlo múltiples veces notarás que algunas veces imprime dos líneas, como has puesto en tu pregunta, y otras veces imprime tres líneas (en ambos casos sin contar la línea de `Tic detenido`).

Lo que sucede es que el último `Tic` sucede al mismo tiempo que el `ticker.Stop` y a veces no dará tiempo de imprimir la última ejecución de `fmt.Println("Tic a las", t)` dependiendo de la carga de tu procesador en ese momento.

Para evitar este comportamiento inconsistente basta con agregar algunos mili segundos al `Sleep` para que le de tiempo suficiente de imprimir las tres veces el `Tic` que está dentro del ciclo.

Algo así:

```
package main

import "time"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1505)
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Ticker detenido")
}
```

Podría darte la falsa impresión de que no debería pasar así dado que `go` es síncrono pero lo que sucede es que al ejecutar `go func()` estás creando una subrutina asíncrona que se ejecuta a la par del `time.Sleep` y por esto es que el programa entero no deja de funcionar mientras el hilo principal está "dormido".

Comment: Tengo una pregunta.¿En Go no hay prioridades como ocurre en java? En java cuando llega a pasar algo como esto se pueden establecer prioridades con setPriority de la clase Thread y así hacer que ciertos hilos tengan preferencia sobre otros cuando llegan al mismo tiempo a solicitar un recurso. Lo pregunto porque esa solución se me hace mas optima que lo que comentas. Aún asi, si eso no existe en Go haré lo de aumentar unos pocos milisegundos al main. Ya me había dado cuenta también de ese comportamiento, pero pense que en Go había una solución mas elegante similar a las prioridades en java

Comment: @abrahamhs No sé si existen prioridades en `Go` pero el problema es que no estás manejando dos `goroutines` para tratar de ponerles prioridad, estás manejando un hilo principal de ejecución y una `goroutine`. La prioridad sólo tendría sentido si fueran dos `goroutines` aunque no sé si existe.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Lo haré con milisegundos, es que cuando se manejan prioridades si se puede poner una prioridad mas alta que la del hilo principal. Pero lo haré con los milisegundos, mi única opción. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: De nada, y busqué pero no encontré nada sobre prioridades https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Comment: Si, en java el main tiene prioridad normal y los hilos que creas le puedes poner prioridad mas alta o mas baja que eso. En Go pense que habia algo como eso ya que veo que combina temas de concurrencia de otros lenguajes con propuestas nuevas y propias, y esta combinación que tiene Go se me hace mas elegante y eficiente. Este lenguaje me parece el que mejor maneja concurrencia de todos los que hay en el mercado.